# Query on Lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

Continuing on exercises in book [Lambda Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0444875085), the question is as follows:

> Suppose a symbol of the λ-calculus
>   alphabet is always 0.5cm wide. Write
>   down a λ-term with length less than 20
>   cm having a normal form with length at
>   least (10^10)^10 lightyear. The speed
>   of light is c = 3 * (10^10) cm/sec.

I have absolutely no idea as to what needs to be done in this question. Can anyone please give me some ***pointers*** to help understand the question and what needs to be done here? Please do not solve or mention the final answer.

Hoping for a reply.

Regards,
darkie

Comment: I think this is a valid question as lambda calculus is becoming more important to programming, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing anything about lambda calculus, I understand the question as following:

You have to write a λ-term in less than 20 cm, where a symbol is 0.5cm, meaning you are allowed less than 40 symbols. This λ-term should expand to a normal form with the length of at least (10^10)^10 = 10^100 lightyears, which results in (10^100)*2*3*(10^10)*24*60*60 symbols. Basically a very long recursive function.

Comment: I think your analysis is well-done, and you show enough to make it easy to write the solution.

Comment: I have a query, how can I be sure that my λ - recursive function would exceed that many symbols? I mean, that is too many symbols to ensure, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is too much to test - which is exactly the point the task is about. You need to define a function, that grows extremely fast. An example for such a function would be the [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). I'm not sure how far this applies in λ-Calculus. Busy Beaver would also be such a function, growing extremely fast over all bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another hint: in lambda calculus, the typical way to represent an integer is by its Church encoding, which is a *unary* representation.   So if you convert the distances into numbers, one thing that would do the trick would be a small function which, when applied to a small number, terminates and produces a very large number.